# With javascript is possible to know the zone of client?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, timezone

Is possible using `javascript`to know the zone/area of client ?

I ask this because in my project i have earthquakes with date in `UTC` but i want to show to client even earthquakes in his time zone and printing also his name zone (for example "Italy").

To show his time zone i will use:

```
getHours()
```

but i don't know if a way to show also name of zone/area

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Comment: What about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: From the browser yes. JS run on a server no. Libraries such as moment.js are very helpful for this.

Comment: With _"zone"_, you mean _"timezone"_?

Comment: console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone) 

result: Europe/Rome ...
italy i dont think it's possible

Comment: @Leo oh yes this is perfect... do you know if is supported by all browsers what you suggest ? Please write an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone‌​)`

result:

`Europe/Rome ...`

but 'italy' i dont think it's possible.

here [Browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat#Browser_compatibility), if I'm not mistaken, they talk about the compatibility of browsers

Example

Chrome  24(version)